# Creating an object without a default constructor

Tags: java, constructor, object-construction

I have a package which has some N number of classes and I'm scanning all the classes and initializing them through a method. All the classes with a default constructor are being initialized but the ones without default(zero argument) constructor throws an exception. Does anyone know how to create an object without default constructor?

P.S. I need a java code.

Comment: You would need to call a defined constructor.

Comment: If your class already has at-least one custom constructor, then compiler won't create default no-args constructor. Eg: If your class has only one argument constructor, then you cannot create your object any other way other than passing args to your constructor

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Class#getConstructors()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29) to find a defined constructor, and call that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html). It explains how to create objects using Java reflection.

Or just Google: java constructor reflection. I got this one using the "I'm feeling lucky" feature